# Save multiple checkbox values to sql database

Tags: jquery, html, sql, checkbox, asp.net-web-api2

I have a html form, and i have also checkboxes in it. Values of checkboxes is coming from SQL-database via Web Api.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $MaterialName = $('#materiallist');  

  function addMaterials(material) {
    $MaterialName.append('<input type="checkbox" >' + material.MaterialName + ' </input>');
  }
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="material" class="col-xs-3 control-label header">Käytetyt materiaalit</label>
  <div class="col-xs-7">
    <div class="checkbox" id="materiallist"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to save those checked values to another SQL-database (named Form), along with the other input values in that form.

I haven't found a solution where all the other input fields also needs to be saved as well, only solutions where is only checkboxes and button. Also, my values are coming from a database, and are not "hard-coded" options.

I tried this:

```
function getCheckedMaterials() {
  var materialArray = [];
  $("#materiallist input:checked").each(function () {
    materialArray.push($(this).val());
  });
  var selected;
  selected = materialArray.join(',');
  alert("You have selected " + selected);
}
```

This doesn't work as I need, because I can't get the values.

All these values from other input fields goes to the Form database when I press the `#tallenna` button. I need the checked values to be saved in `MaterialName` as text.

```
$('#tallenna').click(function () {
  var form = {
    FormFiller: $FormFiller.val(),
    CustomerContact: $CustomerContact.val(),
    ReadyToDate: $ReadyToDate.val(),
    Instructions: $Instructions.val(),
    Amount: $Amount.val(),
    PcsAmount: $PcsAmount.val(),
    ChargeFull: $ChargeFull.val(),
    ChargeByPcs: $ChargeByPcs.val(),
    FreightCost: $FreightCost.val(),
    CustomerName: $CustomerName.val(),
    WorkName: $WorkName.val(),
    MaterialName: getCheckedMaterials // ???? 
  };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be asking how to return the data from the function to the property. As such, add a `return` statement in the function, and invoke it from the property by adding `()` at the end of the function name, like this:

```js
function getCheckedMaterials() {
  var materialArray = $("#materiallist input:checked").map(function () {
    return this.value;
  }).get();
  return materialArray.join(',');
}

$('#tallenna').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var form = {
    // other properties...
    MaterialName: getCheckedMaterials()
  };

  // send 'form' in an AJAX request here...
});
```

I would suggest returning the plain `materialArray` array from the function and sending that in your AJAX request to your WebAPI endpoint. That way you can modelbind it to a `string[]` or `IEnumerable<string>` which makes it easier to work with.

Comment: Got value "on" to database. How do i get "names" of the checked boxes in database? That was the original question.

Comment: Add `value` attributes to the checkbox HTML `$MaterialName.append('<input type="checkbox" value="' + material.MaterialName + '">' + material.MaterialName + ' </input>');`.

Comment: Now there is "foo" in my database, not name of material. MaterialNames are coming from database, i cant put value to every material. Any other idea how to tell that value is same as MaterialName?

Comment: So put the variable in to the `value`..? I've edited it for you.